# What are User Policy and Permission Policy for under SharePoint2010 Web Application?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

What are User Policy and Permission Policy for under SharePoint2010 Web Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These screens allow an administrator to set permissions per web application. They are like site collection permissions, but permission here apply to all sites in a web application.

The "permission policies" define groups of permission rights (similar to permissions levels of a site collection).

```
Full Read - good for search/caching
Full Control - good for global admins
Deny Write - good for public facing
Deny All - good for restricted sites
```

The "user policy" area, then allows you to assign those permission polices to certain users/groups.

The default users policies for example, allow the search account to read all sites in a web application, without having to set permissions individually on each site collection.
Another policy you should add is for the caching account.

An example of a custom policy, would be denying deleting items/version on a whole web application for certain users, maybe for an public facing extended web application.